Optimal cycle for minimizing distance between vectors
I faced this problem recently, and am looking for an efficient solution.
We are given $X = (x_1,...,x_n)$ and $Y = (y_1,...,y_n)$ two vectors with ascending coordinates.
Considering a cycle $\sigma = (i_1\;i_2\;...\;i_n)$, we denote $Y_\sigma = (y_{\sigma(1)},...,y_{\sigma(n)})$ and $D_\sigma = \|X-Y_\sigma\|^2$ where $\|.\|$ is the euclidean norm.
We are looking for a cycle $\sigma_0$ minimizing $D_\sigma$.
The brute force method requires to test the $(n-1)!$ cycles, and thus has a $O(n!)$ complexity. With a dynamic programming approach, I found a $O(n\,2^n)$ solution, but it's still way too much for $n > 15$.
Does anyone find a better algorithm ? (Pay attention that we only look at cycles, and not at every permutations)

I don't understand what you mean cycle $\sigma=(i_1i_2\ldots i_n)$. How is it different from permutation in your problem?

Can you say anything about the motivation for this problem or in what context you encountered it?
